# Equivalent function of `if` statement in R so that it can be used with the pipe operator

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, purrr

Is there a function that does the following ?

```
library(dplyr)

cond = T
if (cond) { 
  print('Hello')
}
# [1] "Hello"

# How can I achieve the same as above with a pipe ? 
print('Hello') %>% function_if(cond)
```

The `purrr::when` and `ifelse` functions don't seem to work here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I added comments in the code

Comment: I would not use a pipe in that situation. Do you have a real-world example you're thinking of? Pipes are typically used to manipulate a data frame over the course of multiple steps. Are you wanting to use an if statement to conditionally manipulate something like a data frame (e.g., perform a certain operation to only those rows that meet your condition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, I don't see utility in this ... but

```r
function_if <- function(data, expr) if (isTRUE(expr)) force(data)
cond <- TRUE
print('Hello') %>%
  function_if(cond)
# [1] "Hello"
print('Hello') %>%
  function_if(cond) %>%
  class()
# [1] "Hello"                 # <-- action of 'print'
# [1] "character"             # <-- output from 'class', to show that
print('Hello') %>%            # <-- this never happens here
  function_if(FALSE) %>%
  class()
# [1] "NULL"                  # <-- output from 'class', no 'print' output
```

I don't know that I would ever use this, to be candid.

The way it works: `data` (which can be any object) is defined lazily here. The order of execution here is: `%>%`, `function_if`, and only if `isTRUE(expr)`, it forces evaluation of `data`. If it was true, then `data` is evaluated and returned; if it was not true, then `function_if` does not force data, so its lazy presence is never instantiated, and `NULL` is implicitly returned instead.

Perhaps a better name for *this* function would be `stoppipe_if_not`, meaning that all data-flow in the pipe (whether `data.frame` or anything else) will not be passed along if the `cond`ition is not precisely `TRUE`.

Comment: `force` seems unnecessary here.

Comment: `function_if <- function(data, expr) if (isTRUE(expr)) data ` works

Comment: Isn't there a built-in function that does this ? I would be surprised if there were none

Comment: Yes, `force` was included as much to be declarative as anything else, it should be safe to remove. The only time I can think that it _might_ be different is if there is a long chain before this where `data` may still be lazy, whereas `force(data)` will require its instantiation _right now_. Perhaps not using `force` would be friendlier if this is the case. I know of no function that does this, I also don't know where it would be useful, but if you have a good use-case then I suggest you request a FR at `dplyr` or `purrr`.

Comment: What is a FR ? Feature request ?

Comment: yes, FR is a feature request, PR is a pull request (or MR is a merge request, for gitlab users)